# MySQL where in and not in

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help on this query please on how to get the output i want?

I am looking for client who has a tag "Kane" but not "Andrew".

I am expecting the output:

> "client 3" only because on "client 1" has a tag Andrew

```
INSERT INTO `client` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Client 1'),
  ('2', 'Client 2'),
  ('3', 'Client 3'),
  ('4', 'Client 4');

 INSERT INTO `tag` (`id`, `client_id`, `tag`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'Kane'),
  ('2', '1', 'Andrew'),
  ('3', '2', 'Andrew'),
  ('4', '3', 'Kane'),
  ('5', '3', 'James'),
  ('6', '4', 'Andrew');

## mysql query
select * from client where 
exists (
select client_id 
    from tag 
    where tag.client_id = client.id 
    and tag in ('Kane')
    and tag not in ( 'Andrew' )
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48955/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the most efficient way, but this will work:

```
select * from client where 
exists (
select client_id 
    from tag 
    where tag.client_id = client.id 
    and tag in ('Kane')
)
and not exists (
select client_id 
    from tag 
    where tag.client_id = client.id 
    and tag in ('Andrew')
)
```

The problem with your query was it was trying to apply both `tag in ('Kane')`
    and `tag not in ( 'Andrew' )` to each and every row at the same time. Since the first clause is restrictive, it made the second clause redundant. You have to ask the two questions separately.

Comment: thank you. Do you know if there is any performance with this query for large database?

Comment: not specifically. Make sure your table is properly indexed. What do you define as "large" anyway? And what hardware is it running on, number of concurrent connections, number of concurrent instances of this particular query, all that will have an impact as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, with `NOT IN()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Client C
JOIN tag t on C.id = t.client_id
WHERE tag = 'Kane'
AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT client_id FROM tag WHERE tag = 'Andrew')
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48955/22/0)

Basically you get all clients that have `tag = 'Kane'` then remove those that have a instance of `tag = 'Andrew'` using the `NOT IN()`

Comment: I like it but not sure the OP wants multiple rows showing the same client

Comment: @kbball Good point, it's a little unclear the exact output desired.  If he wants just the row with 'Kane' this works, if he wants all rows for client 3 he will have to go a level deeper.  Actually, it looks like he just wants the one row for client 3, so really my select about should be `c.*`.

Comment: the tag could be more than one, for example: client who has tag `"Kane, Andrew" but not "Kane, James"`, etc

Answer (score 2):

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   client.id
 , client.name
FROM 
 CLIENT 
INNER JOIN 
 tag
ON
 client.id = tag.client_id 
GROUP BY 
   client.id
 , client.name
HAVING 
   SUM(tag = 'Kane')
 AND
   NOT SUM(tag = 'Andrew')
```

**Result**

```
    id  name      
------  ----------
     3  Client 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the brute force method:

```
SELECT name
FROM client
WHERE id
IN
(SELECT client_id
 FROM tag
 WHERE tag = 'Kane') 
AND id NOT IN
(SELECT client_id
 FROM tag
 WHERE tag = 'Andrew')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the fastest option.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM client AS c
INNER JOIN tag AS t1 ON a.id = t.client_id
LEFT JOIN tag AS t2 ON a.id = t2.client_id AND t2.tag = 'Andrew'
WHERE t1.tag = 'Kane'
AND t2.tag IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work for your situation.

```
 select * from client a
join tag b on a.id = b.client_id
where b.tag = 'Kane'
and not exists
(select * from tag c where c.client_id = b.client_id and tag = 'Andrew' )
```

When you have 2 conflicting filters on the join the second filter is combined with the first filter and clashes.

The solution is to exists or not exists for the second filter, this way the second condition gets applied to the results of the query and is treated as a separate condition.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.